# MEANjs custom bootstrap theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, styles, themes, mean-stack, meanjs

I'm a noob to MEANjs and to Bootstrap.

I'm trying to add custom theme styles to the standard  core.css that comes with MEANjs.

You can see in my CSS that I've added the 'background:"blue" !important' attribute to the svg style.  However, the background isn't getting set to blue.

I guess this means that the core.css file isn't where I'm going to put the theme for the core module, but I don't really know where this should go.

Any hints or pointers would be appreciated.

/core/css/core.css

```
.content {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.undecorated-link:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
}
.ng-invalid.ng-dirty{
    border-color:#FA787E;
}
.ng-valid.ng-dirty{
    border-color:#78FA89;
}

.visualization{
    border-radius:10;
    border-color:"green";
    background:"blue" !important;
}

svg{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    fill:"blue" !important;
}
```

/core/views/home.client.view.html

```
<section data-ng-controller="HomeController" data-ng-init="init()">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <svg
            ng-controller="VisualizationController"
            class="visualization"
            id="visualization_0"
            height="500"
            width="500">
            <circle cx="50" cy="100" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red"></circle>
        </svg>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Did you create any subfolders within your angular module? If I recall, when creating it, it gives you the option to do so.

Also, could you provide a breakdown of your folder hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Your MEAN code is right and I think the CSS is wrong. Have you tried:

```
svg path {
    fill: blue;
}​
```

I must admit I don't like the way MEAN handles CSS. It forces you into a weird folder structure and then just concatenates the files. Using LESSCSS to build from the bootstrap source and including custom modules would be better

Answer (score 0):

I believe even the development env uses the uglified-minified version of the CSS.

Use the grunt command:

```
grunt build
```

this will perform uglify and cssmin which will update the css you are viewing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate folder for your themes css and reference it in your default.js file.

For example: navigate to your public folder. Create a new folder inside called "Theme". Place all your css files related to your theme in this folder.

Next, navigate to the "config" folder. Go into the assets folder and find "default.js". 
Below you'll see an array where you can add your css path to be loaded into your page. Use a comma to add multiple files if need be.

```js
module.exports = {
  client: {
    lib: {
      css: [
        // bower:css
        'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
        'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css',
        'public/theme/theme.css' // THIS IS THE THEME CSS
        // endbower
      ],
      js: [
        // bower:js
        'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
        'public/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
        'public/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
        'public/lib/angular-messages/angular-messages.js',
        'public/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
        'public/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
        'public/lib/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.js',
        'public/lib/owasp-password-strength-test/owasp-password-strength-test.js'
        // endbower
      ],
```

Once this is done, go view your page in a browser. Right click and inspect your pages "head" tag to make sure your css is loading successfully.

Comment: Although this may minimally answer the question, providing
additional details of how to do this would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.